# Are these anchors suitable for use in brick?

Tags: repair, walls

These were included in a home surveillance camera I purchased. Are they called screw anchors?

I know they open up to provide better anchor when a screw is tightened into it, but should they be used on wooden walls only, or are they also good to be used in a brick wall?

[image]

Comment: An anchor is an anchor by any other name, including "rose". I've revised your title to make the post more practically useful to the community. Feel free to revise further.

Comment: Are these anchors suitable for use in brick to mount a half ounce camera? sure, but not much else.

Answer (score 8):

> Are they called screw anchors?

This varies based on region/manufacturer. Any of these are acceptable:

- Anchor
- Ribbed anchor
- Drywall anchor
- Screw anchor
- Probably several more...

---

> but should they be used on wooden walls only

Heck no. Wood is plenty strong to hold a bare screw.

Using an anchor in wood would actually be weaker. You *could* use this in wood if you must re-use and existing hole which has been compromised due to overtightening and spinning out.

---

> are they also good to be used in a brick wall?

Yes, these can go into brick/masonry walls assuming you don't have masonry screws such as [Tapcon](https://www.tapcon.com/Products/Genuine-Tapcon-Screw-Anchors/Genuine-Tapcon/).

Answer (score 6):

I would not use them on wood - there wood screws that will do a better job.

Those will be ok for masonry ie brick / concrete, but better quality ones exist. For drywall, there are similar plastic plugs which are longer and the tightening action causes “ears” to spread to increase the load area.

This is an image of a metal version, plastic ones are similar in function:
[image]
Easily found in any good hardware store...
Found them here: `https://www.screwfix.com/search?search=drywall+anchors`

Known as rawlplugs based on one manufacturer, much like vacuum cleaners are called hoovers…

Comment: Can you include a picture of the plastic plugs that have "ears" that you mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a drywall anchor.

Wood does not require an anchor for a screw unless it is very thin wood or if using a machine screw or bolt with fine threads.

For a brick wall and a screw as small as this, I'd start with a Tapcon screw, which also does not need an anchor.

For drywall, these plastic anchors are often more trouble than they're worth.  A 1.25" drywall screw or a picture hook and nail are usually as good or better than a plastic anchor, unless you already have an oversize hole in the wall.

Comment: It's a solid wall anchor.

Comment: @Tetsujin Actually there are such drywall anchors models (note the wide fins around the shank on OP photo) - https://diy.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/diy/fullset/2013/6/11/0/Original_anchor-and-bolt-in-drywall_4x3.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.1280.960.suffix/1420678665920.jpeg I personally would not trust them though - too small fins and too flimsy spreading back ...

Comment: Link is geofenced. I would never use one of those on a hollow wall - frankly, I wouldn't use one that small on brick either. There's a common description in the UK, which comes from the most common size/colour of the trademarked Rawlplug - "brown plugs" [it's googlable here, you'll find the right thing]

Comment: The fins are (maybe) to go into the plasterboard/plaster , but the tails out the back are to go into a solid wall and won't work if they end up in free space behind the plasterboard.

Answer (score -1):

These are actually anchors. If they come with screws, then they are screw anchors. They will work in drywall for light loads like your camera. They can also be used in brick, concrete and block but there are better anchors for those materials like Tapcons. These anchors don't need to be used on wooded walls because the wood will hold the screws just fine.